# Change img src attribute when hovered JS / PHP

Tags: javascript, php, html, css

I have the list of users registered on

table: *ch_users*

Where my PHP code aims to select all of the users and fetch.

*ch_user* contains (userId, name, quote, position, thumbnail, hover_image)

What I'm trying to achieve is whenever the user hovers the specific image. another image will appear.

Here are my current codes.

```
 <div id="gallery-container1">
 <div class="row-content1">
 <?php
            try{
            $connect = new PDO("mysql:host=$host;dbname=$database", $username, $password);
            $connect->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);

            $query = "SELECT * FROM ch_users";
            $data = $connect->query($query);
            foreach($data as $instructor_row){
            ?>


            <div class="img-container1">
              <div class="img-content1">
                  <a href="#">
                    <img src="img/instructors/<?php echo $instructor_row['thumbnail'];?>" />
                    </a>
                </div>
            </div>


            <?php
                    }//end of foreach
                }//end of try
                catch(PDOException $error)
                {
                    $error->getMessage();
                }
                ?>

  <div class="clearfix"></div>

  </div>


  </div>
```

CSS:

```
#gallery-container1{

margin-top:15vh;
text-align:center;
margin-bottom:10vh;
}
.img-container1 {
width:16.5%;
display:inline-block;
margin-bottom:30px;
}
.img-content1 {
padding:0;
height:auto;
overflow:hidden;
box-shadow:0 .8px .8px #ccc;
width:80%;
 }

.img-content1 img {
 width:100%;
 height:auto;
 }

 .clearfix {
 clear:both;
  }

  @media only screen and (max-width: 560px) {
 .img-container1 {
 width:98%;
 margin-left:10%;
 } 
 }

 @media only screen and (min-width: 600px)and (max-width: 900px) {
 .img-container1 {
  width:38%;
  padding:1%;
 } 
  }
```

I've been following some threads. Mostly to change the attribute SRC of an img. JS is the appropriate way. So I came up with the idea of this code. But I don't know how can I implement this.

```
<script>
 function hover(element) {
 element.setAttribute('src', 'img/instructor/5h.jpg');
 }

  function unhover(element) {
 element.setAttribute('src', 'img/instructor/5.jpg');
 }
</script>

 <div class="img-container1">
  <div class="img-content1">
    <a href="#">
      <img src="img/instructor/<?php echo $instructors_row['thumbnail'];?>" onmouseover="hover(this);" onmouseout="unhover(this);" />
     </a>
  </div>
</div>
```

*$instructor_row["hover_image"];* is a field that contains image that will appear whenever the user hovers the fetched images.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can achieve this without using Javascript. Try something below:

PHP:

```
<div class="img-container1">
  <div class="img-content1">
    <a href="#">
      <img src="img/instructors/<?php echo $instructor_row['thumbnail'];?>" class="thumbnail">
      <img src="img/instructors/<?php echo $instructor_row['hover_image'];?>" class="hover-image">
    </a>
  </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.img-content1 > img.hover-image,
.img-content1:hover > img.thumbnail {
  display: none;
}
.img-content1:hover > img.hover-image {
  display: block;
}
```

1. Render both images and hide one of them.
2. Toggle showing them when parent container is hovered.